# Multiple update from multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-update

Looks like a simple question but I couldn't get what I need in MsSql while I can do it easily in MySQL and Oracle.

**In MySQL:**
UPDATE table_spec_data 
SET coverage=33 
WHERE (specification_id, data_id) IN 
( 
(247,1),
(248,2),
(249,3)
);

**In Oracle:**
UPDATE table_spec_data 
SET coverage=33 
WHERE (specification_id, data_id) IN 
( 
SELECT 247,1 FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 248,2 FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 249,3 FROM DUAL
);

Does anyone knows how to do it with **MSSqlServer** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do it the hard way:

```
 UPDATE table_spec_data SET coverage=33 WHERE 
     (specification_id = 247 AND data_id = 1)
     OR (specification_id = 248 AND data_id = 2)
     OR (specification_id = 249 AND data_id = 3)
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much. I was expecting something quicker... but maybe this execution plan is optimized on SQLServer. Let's see the performances...